text-wrap within cells when using different column types with longtable
I was working on the following table and try to figure out how to wrap the text inside the last two column while keeping it aligned to the left; I also wish, to have to content of the adjacent cell centered both vertically and horizontally — I guess I can do that with the m column type but I'm unsure how I can do so when using \siunitx...
Nevertheless, the main issue is that I'm struggling with how to figure out a way to do so. Below, a MWE which should help to to understand the problem; any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
textfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\smallerbaseline}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt plus \textwidth}
\setlength\LTright{0pt plus \textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{%
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    S[table-format=2.0] c *{2} l 
}

\caption{\dots}
\label{table:model_sel} \\
\toprule  
\multicolumn{1}{c}{NUMBER} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ORIGIN} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{POPULATION} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{SAMPLES} \\
\midrule

14 & Papua New Guinea & Papuan & HGDP00540-1, HGDP00543, HGDP00545-55  \\
10 & Africa & Dinka, Luhya, Mende and Yoruba & DNK05, DNK07, DNK11; HG03078, HG03085; HGDP00928, HGDP00932, HGDP00936; NA19023, NA19044 \\
10 & Europe & Czech, English, French, Hungarian and Spanish & HG00126, HG00128; HG01503-4; HGDP00526, HGDP00530, HGDP00533; NA15202-3, NA15728 \\
10 & Central East Asia & Han, Japanese, Kinh and Mongol & HG01600, HG01846; HGDP00749, HGDP00773, NA18940; HGDP00775, HGDP00783, HGDP00785, HGDP01223, HGDP01228;  \\
1 & Altai Mountains & archaic & Neanderthals \\
1 & Denisova Cave & archaic & Denisovans \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


Here are two examples using longtblr from the tabularray package. The first example contains vertically and horizontally centered text in the first two columns, as requested. The second, more compact example uses top left alignment for the first two columns in order to improve readability:

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
textfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\smallerbaseline}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
                 caption = {\dots},
                 label = {table:model_sel},
                 ]
                 {
                 colspec = {S[table-format=2] c m{4cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X }, 
                 width = \linewidth,
                 rowhead = 1,
                 row{1} = {halign=c}, 
                 column{1-4} = {valign=m}
                 }
\toprule  
{{NUMBER}} &
ORIGIN &
POPULATION &
SAMPLES \\
\midrule

14 & Papua New Guinea & Papuan & HGDP00540-1, HGDP00543, HGDP00545-55  \\
10 & Africa & Dinka, Luhya, Mende and Yoruba & DNK05, DNK07, DNK11; HG03078, HG03085; HGDP00928, HGDP00932, HGDP00936; NA19023, NA19044 \\
10 & Europe & Czech, English, French, Hungarian and Spanish & HG00126, HG00128; HG01503-4; HGDP00526, HGDP00530, HGDP00533; NA15202-3, NA15728 \\
10 & Central East Asia & Han, Japanese, Kinh and Mongol & HG01600, HG01846; HGDP00749, HGDP00773, NA18940; HGDP00775, HGDP00783, HGDP00785, HGDP01223, HGDP01228;  \\
1 & Altai Mountains & archaic & Neanderthals \\
1 & Denisova Cave & archaic & Denisovans \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\clearpage

\begin{longtblr}[
                 caption = {\dots},
                 label = {table:model_sel},
                 ]
                 {
                 colspec = {l p{3cm} p{4cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X }, 
                 width = \linewidth,
                 rowhead = 1,
                 }
\toprule  
{{NO.}} &
ORIGIN &
POPULATION &
SAMPLES \\
\midrule

14 & Papua New Guinea & Papuan & HGDP00540-1, HGDP00543, HGDP00545-55  \\
10 & Africa & Dinka, Luhya, Mende and Yoruba & DNK05, DNK07, DNK11; HG03078, HG03085; HGDP00928, HGDP00932, HGDP00936; NA19023, NA19044 \\
10 & Europe & Czech, English, French, Hungarian and Spanish & HG00126, HG00128; HG01503-4; HGDP00526, HGDP00530, HGDP00533; NA15202-3, NA15728 \\
10 & Central East Asia & Han, Japanese, Kinh and Mongol & HG01600, HG01846; HGDP00749, HGDP00773, NA18940; HGDP00775, HGDP00783, HGDP00785, HGDP01223, HGDP01228;  \\
1 & Altai Mountains & archaic & Neanderthals \\
1 & Denisova Cave & archaic & Denisovans \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}


wonderful! Thanks a lot once again; unfortunately, as I'm quite new to TeX, once I learned a system I try to figure out solutions sticking to it, it's not ideal but I'm on a deadline for my thesis and attempting to balance out aspects of learning TeX language and actual writing. That said, I really appreciate the two options using different packages; I went for the second one since it looks more clean and less space is "wasted", as you indicated – again, my poor foresight in thinking about the problem in TeX environment. I think, I mostly got a grasp of the structure and the code!

one thing I noticed is that my caption does not conform anymore to the style I set for other tables and figure. It hangs, the size is bigger as well as the interline. Is there a way to fix this? Also, it appears is shows in full in the LOT as opposed to only the short caption. Let me know thanks!

Regarding the LOT: You can use the entry as follows: \begin{longtblr}[                  caption = {full caption},                  entry = {short caption for the toc},

amazing I missed out on that. In the meantime, I found the theme personalization, which with the following does almost what I want:\NewTblrTheme{std}{%   \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\selectfont}   \SetTblrStyle{caption-sep}{font=\small\selectfont}   \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small\selectfont} }. For the sake of me, though, I cannot find anything changing the alignment or the spacing...

If alignment refers to the hanging indentation, you're probebly looking for \SetTblrStyle{caption}{hang=0pt}.

Indeed, I stupidly keep trying with caption-alignment whereas the parameter controlling the indent for the caption is hang. I'm trying to figure out the parameter for the \baselinestretch

for caption see new package tblr-extras. It enable use of ``captionpackage settings for captions inlongtblrandtalltblr` tables

@leandriis I found this more comprehensive guide to edit also the (Continued) portion of the caption: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633931/how-can-i-remove-the-hanging-indent-within-the-table-caption-on-the-second-cont. Still trying to figure out the baselinestretch.

@Zarko That is what I was testing initially; however, it gave me some issues loading it in Overleaf. Not sure why...

Package is very new (from this year, I think) and maybe it is not installed in Overleaf yet (they renew their repository only one times per year, usual at late autumn). So you need to install it in directory yourself or better ask them staff for help.
